# AWS Not able to set work_mem for an aurora serverless instance (postgres)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

Recently we migrated to AWS aurora serverless(postgres) from a mongodb.

We have some complex /heavy sort operations , so found that the performance can be improved by adjusting the work_mem.I tried to set it with an editor like PGAdmin by connecting to the instance , but it is reset to default 4MB after sometime .

Any idea how can i update this

We are using serverless (2-8 ACUS)
[image]

i tried with the below command

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're setting work_mem for the session. Change it in parameter group instead to be applied globally.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but how to set a work_mem if the ram size is dynamic based on the load

Comment: I suggest to monitor an activity in your DB and set some work_mem which will handle the load. In case you need to dynamically update work_mem based on the load, I'm not sure, that AWS has built-in solution for that kind of operation. I can suggest using cloudwatch alarms and lambda function to update current param group based on your custom requirements.